# jMeter post body data is not mapped to bean

Tags: post, jmeter, httprequest

The data sent in body data is ignored.
Bean will be created with its default data instead of the data sent via post.

[image: Post request]

[image: Request Header]

Output Body :

```
POST http://localhost:9080/myapp/createEntity
POST data:
{
    "entity.name":"name",
    "entity.description":"description",
    "otherEntity.name":"name"
}
Cookie Data:
......
```

Header :

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 378
Host: localhost:9080
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.12 (Java/1.8.0_262)
```

Though, the request works fine with a GET :
[image: GET request]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is form data, the right content-type to use is : application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Instead of using the body data, i did sent it as regular parameters. (This way, no need to care about the body data format.)

Works perfectly now !

[image]